# Unused argument in a nested ifelse statement

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the following ifelse statement

```
ifelse(test = (size == "small"), yes = (config(toImageButtonOptions = list(format = "png", width = 601, height = 500)))
       , no = (ifelse(test = (size == "medium"), yes = (config(toImageButtonOptions = list(format = "png", width = 1241, height = 750))),
                no = (config(toImageButtonOptions = list(format = "png", width = 1698, height = 900))))))
```

Where size is an input to the function below.
I receive the following error

```
Error in ifelse(., test = (size == "small"), yes = (config(toImageButtonOptions = list(format = "png",  : 
  unused argument (.)
```

The entire function

```
fPlotPricefloat <- function(mData, dDate, dY, dGroup, dtitle_name, dYLab ,dYmin, dYmax, dBreak, dateBreak, spreadin, size = c("small", "medium", "large")){
  
  #Define Names in legend
  dNames <- sort(unique(mData[,dGroup]))
  
  ## Define Date interval
  dateLab <- c("%h%Y")
  dateBreak <- dateBreak
  
  #Define plotb
  p <- ggplotly(ggplot(data=mData, mapping = aes(x=as.Date(mData[,dDate]), y=mData[,dY],
                                   color=mData[,dGroup], 
                                   text = paste0("<b>Tradedate:, </b>", as.Date(mData[,dDate]),"<br>",
                                                 paste0("<b>Spread to ", spreadin, ": </b>"), round(mData[,dY],2), "<br>",
                                                 "<b>AssetID: </b>", mData[,dGroup]),
                                   group = 1)) + 
    labs(x=NULL, y=dYLab, title = dtitle_name,
         caption = "Source: Jyske Bank") +
    geom_line(size=1) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
    scale_colour_manual(name="",values=setNames(c(vRGB_Large[1:length(dNames)]),c(dNames[1:length(dNames)]))) + 
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = dateBreak, date_labels = dateLab) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(dYmin, dYmax, by = dBreak)) + 
    theme_bw()+
    theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0,size=8,face="bold"),
          plot.caption = element_text(size=6, face = "italic"),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.01, hjust=1),legend.position = "bottom",
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          legend.text=element_text(size=6),
          legend.key.width = unit(0.5,"cm"),
          legend.key.height = unit(0.1,"cm"),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
          axis.line.y = element_line(),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 7),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 8)), tooltip = "text") %>% 
layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.4, y = -0.2),
             annotations = list(x = 1, y = -0.3,
                                text = "<b>Source: Jyske Bank</b>",
                                showarrow = F,
                                xref = 'paper',
                                yref = 'paper',
                                xanchor = 'right',
                                yanchor = 'auto',
                                xshift = 0,
                                yshift = 0,
                                font = list(size = 10))) %>%
    ifelse(test = (size == "small"), yes = (config(toImageButtonOptions = list(format = "png", width = 601, height = 500)))
           , no = (ifelse(test = (size == "medium"), yes = (config(toImageButtonOptions = list(format = "png", width = 1241, height = 750))),
                    no = (config(toImageButtonOptions = list(format = "png", width = 1698, height = 900))))))

p}
```

The ifelse statement is used to configure the size of the downloaded image of ggplotly. The function is to be used in RShiny.

Comment: Are you piping something to the ifelse?

Comment: Hello! I have written the entire function in the post now to make it clear.

Comment: And you have indeed a `%>%` just before, so you are piping to `ifelse`. If I understand correctly, you are trying to pass additional options to `ggplotly`, but it won't work this way. You may put all the `ifelse`s inside the call to `config` (and pipe to `config` as expected), or compute the option list before the call to `ggplotly` and save it to a local variable, then pass it to `config`.